# How to store command arguments which contain double quotes in an array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a Bash script which generates, stores and modifies values in an array. These values are later used as arguments for a command.

For a MCVE I thought of an arbitrary command `bash -c 'echo 0="$0" ; echo 1="$1"'` which explains my problem. I will call my command with two arguments `-option1=withoutspace` and `-option2="with space"`. So it would look like this

```
> bash -c 'echo 0="$0" ; echo 1="$1"' -option1=withoutspace -option2="with space"
```

if the call to the command would be typed directly into the shell. It prints

```
0=-option1=withoutspace
1=-option2=with space
```

In my Bash script, the arguments are part of an array. However

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGUMENTS=()
ARGUMENTS+=('-option1=withoutspace')
ARGUMENTS+=('-option2="with space"')
bash -c 'echo 0="$0" ; echo 1="$1"' "${ARGUMENTS[@]}"
```

prints

```
0=-option1=withoutspace
1=-option2="with space"
```

which still shows the double quotes (because they are interpreted literally?). What works is

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGUMENTS=()
ARGUMENTS+=('-option1=withoutspace')
ARGUMENTS+=('-option2=with space')
bash -c 'echo 0="$0" ; echo 1="$1"' "${ARGUMENTS[@]}"
```

which prints again

```
0=-option1=withoutspace
1=-option2=with space
```

What do I have to change to make `ARGUMENTS+=('-option2="with space"')` work as well as `ARGUMENTS+=('-option2=with space')`?

(Maybe it's even entirely wrong to store arguments for a command in an array? I'm open for suggestions.)

Comment: What's wrong with just omitting the double quotes, as you did in your second example?

Comment: In general, quotes go *around* data, not *in* data. In the first example, with the arguments supplied directly, the double-quotes are *around* part of the second argument, not actually part of the argument itself. When you store double-quotes in an array element, they're data, not shell syntax, so they do get passed as part of the argument itself. Solution: just leave 'em out, as in your second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes. Write the options exactly as you would on the command line.

```
ARGUMENTS+=(-option1=withoutspace)
ARGUMENTS+=(-option2="with space")
```

Note that this is exactly equivalent to your second option:

```
ARGUMENTS+=('-option1=withoutspace')
ARGUMENTS+=('-option2=with space')
```

`-option2="with space"` and `'-option2=with space'` both evaluate to the same string. They're two ways of writing the same thing.

> (Maybe it's even entirely wrong to store arguments for a command in an array? I'm open for suggestions.)

It's the exact right thing to do. Arrays are perfect for this. Using a flat string would be a mistake.